# QGIS Snapping is not aligned with layers

Tags: qgis, snapping

I was trying to draw lines based on hex grid, but snapping give me wrong position of hex corner. [image: Here is the example]

As you can see, I used snapping-advanced-25 pixel from hex grid, but it is not aligned hex grid. It is off from hex grids a bit.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I think you need to play around a little with the settings in the snapping options. They can be hard to work out, but some trial and error will find a solution. Make sure that you have snap to vertex and segment for the layer you wish to use as the template. And you could try using map units instead of pixels.

Comment: Works for me. Do your hex layer, lines layer and project share the same CRS (EPSG:32652)? How did you create the hex grid? Did you use any offset styling for that?